# Problem uploading image on multi-part form via iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, image

I am trying to write an iPhone app that will allow me to upload a jpg via multi-part form.

Sometimes, the uploaded photo looks corrupted on the server with weird pixels and the photo looks cropped.

What could be the reason for that?
How come I don't get a http error response from the server? (upload backend is written in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64 encoding like shown below

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(145.0, 145.0));

```
[takephoto.layer  renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *LargeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(LargeImage, 0.25); 

NSString *strImageFinalBASE64 =[data base64Encoding];
```

takePhoto can be your UIImageView:

IBOutlet UIImageView *takephoto;